# How to use onOpen trigger to populate current Date field on Google Forms

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms, triggers

I am very new to Google Apps Script, but I have previous experience creating Google Forms.  I created a Google Form in which the first input is "Date".  I want to have the current date pre-filled as soon as the Google Form opens without using pre-filled URLs.  Is there a way to use the onOpen trigger to pre-fill this field with the current date?

Please see below for the code I wrote so far (I commented out the last two lines because I kept getting an error message while running this function).  Overall, I want to call this function every time the Google Form opens, before the user starts filling out the form.

```
function inputDate(){
     var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "PST", "yyyy-MM-dd");
     Logger.log(formattedDate);
     var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
     var formResponse = form.createResponse();
     var items = form.getItems();
     var formItem = items[0].asDateItem();
     //var response = formItem.createResponse(formattedDate);
     //formResponse.withItemResponse(response);
}
```

Comment: Welcome. This is not possible.

Comment: Fantastic! An impossible problem to tackle as my first post.  I currently have the google form set up as an optional input, so users can leave it blank.  My plan B was to edit it on the Google Sheets side using the onFormSubmit trigger.  Essentially (no code yet):
If new Row has blank date, input current date, else do nothing.  Thoughts?

Comment: Consider the following: if the "date" is blank use the date part of the timestamp.

Comment: That was my original workaround, but I wanted to see if there was another way.  Thanks for the quick clarification!